# An inequality question involving non-negative integers

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, integers

I am trying to prove something then I hit a stumbling block in the form of this problem.

Let $a,b,c,d$ be non-negative integers such that:

$c,d$ are fixed

$\max a=d$

$$a\geq b$$

$$c\geq b$$

$$d\geq a$$

$$d> c$$

I want to show that $a\geq c$ and here is my idea.

I consider the difference $a-c$. This difference is either positive, negative, or zero.

If the difference is positive or zero then I can say that $a\geq c$.

If the difference is negative then that implies that $a<c$ but since $a\leq d$ this will imply that $d$ can be less than $c$ which is a contradiction since $d>c$.

So I can only have that $a-c$ is positive or zero thus $a\geq c$.

Is my reasoning correct here? Can you suggest an alternate or correct proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is false.

Try $a=2, b=1, c=3, d=4$. Then  $d \gt c \gt a \gt b$ and this satisfies your four original inequalities but $a \not \ge c$.

Your error is in saying *"If the difference is negative then that implies that $a<c$ but since $a\leq d$ this will imply that $d$ can be less than $c$ which is a contradiction since $d\geq c$"* as it only leads to a contradiction if $d$ must be less than $c$, and that is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I was not able to include this in my question. I have that $d$ and $c$ are fixed with $c<d$ while $a$ can vary with $\max a=d$. Sorry. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: I do not think that affects my point

Comment: My idea is that it is always possible to arrive at a contradiction if I have that $a<c$. In particular when $a=d$.

Comment: If $a=d$ and $d \ge c$ then $a \ge c$.  But if $d \gt c \gt b$ and all three are fixed, then $a$ can take values with $d \ge a \ge c$, or $a$ can take values with $c \gt a \ge b$, and in the latter case there is no contradiction.

Comment: Yes. $a$ can take values from $[b,d]$. If $b,c,d$ are fixed with $b\leq c <d$ then there are three possibilities. Either all the values of $a$ are in $[c,d]$, all the values of $a$ are in $[b,c)$, or some values of $a$ are in $[c,d]$ while some are in $[b,c)$. But we have that $\max a=d$ so that eliminates the possibility that all values of $a$ are in $[b,c)$.

Comment: I think I'm seeing it now. If some values of a are in $[c,d]$ while some are in $[b,c)$ then the relationship between $a$ and $c$ is $a<c$ if $a\in [b,c)$ or $a\geq c$ if $a\in [c,d]$. If I want a relationship between $a$ and $c$ that holds for all $a$ then the condition that $\max a=d$ forces all values of $a$ to be in $[c,d]$ and $a\geq c$.